# retrieve data from OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, json, arraylist, onclick, onitemclicklistener

I have to read json file, a two fields : name and id_name. I created an Array List. The user see only names. When a user click the name, i have to get the **id**. I present you only part of AssyncTask doInBackground procedure. In addition I created class Name  with two parameters name and id.

please help me. here is my code.

```
protected ArrayList<Name> doInBackground(String... params) {

            ArrayList<Name> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
            String result = "";
            ......

             for (int i = 0; i < rootArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject nameObject = rootArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String name = nameObject.getString("name");
                    String id = nameObject.getString("id_name");

                    nameList.add(new NAME(name, id));

                }

            return nameList;
        }

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String my_id = adapter.getItem(position).toString();

            }
        });
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Сan i ask you another question on this topic? The next step of my app, is to retrieve four variables(in this case all of them are characters) in Json file, and pass every one of them to another intent. How can i pass the values of four to onPostExecute? And as i unerstand, i can do intent i onPostExecute? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                TextView  tv_ID=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_id);//Check your xml and set proper ID
                String my_id =tv_ID.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(CurrentActivity.this, my_id , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

Comment: i think he's not having id textview in xml. He's showing only name textview.

Comment: @DharmbirSingh then your logic true

Comment: Thank you. Сan i ask you another question on this topic? The next step of my app, is to retrieve four variables(in this case all of them are characters) in Json file, and pass every one of them to another intent. How can i pass the values of four to onPostExecute? And as i understand, i can do intent i onPostExecute? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Declare your array global for this activity like

```
ArrayList<Name> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then

```
protected ArrayList<Name> doInBackground(String... params) {

            String result = "";
            ......

             if(nameList != null)
                nameList.clear();

             for (int i = 0; i < rootArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject nameObject = rootArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String name = nameObject.getString("name");
                    String id = nameObject.getString("id_name");

                    nameList.add(new NAME(name, id));

                }

            return nameList;
        }


listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                      Name name = nameList.get(position);
                      String id = name.getId();
                      String id = name.getName();

            }
        });
```

**Note:** If you don't have getter method for Name model then create getter method.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Сan i ask you another question on this topic? The next step of my app, is to retrieve four variables(in this case all of them are characters) in Json file, and pass every one of them to another intent. How can i pass the values of four to onPostExecute? And as i unerstand, i can do intent i onPostExecute? Thank you

Comment: @AlexeyShpaner Yes, you can pass but you can pass in intent when you want to open next activity. And please accept my answer if it is solved your problem. Thanks

Comment: Of course. I don;t understand how can i pass values of four variables from doInBackground to onPostExecute? Can you let me an example please?

Comment: Make 4 global variables and then assign value in doInBackground and access in postExecute. Hope it will help you. if its not helpful then please paste your class code here http://pastebin.com/

Comment: i will try now, but what kind of data is? i have to write in AsyncTask  :   public class DownLoad extends AsyncTask <String, Void, ArrayList<Name>. What i should write instead of ArrayList<Name>?

Comment: how can i know what kind of data coming from server. So make it string if its coming string from server otherwise int.

Comment: @AlexeyShpaner Please accept this answer and don't forgot to subscribe this channel for more updates on mobile technology **https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCA5HRmlkT7bqbO56EIlT0UQ**

Answer (score 0):

Try
ListView.get(position);
Instead Of
Adapter.get(position);